# EF code first; many-to-many collections are null?

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-relationship

With EF many to many relationships, do I have to instantiate the corresponding collections of the objects manually?

Like...

```
public class Class1 {
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set;
  public List<Class2> OtherObjects {get; set;}
}

public class Class2 {
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set;
  public List<Class1> OtherObjects {get; set;}
}
```

And somewhere else...

```
Class1 c = new Class1 {
  OtherObjects = new List<Class2>(); // necessary? Do I have to do this?
};

c.OtherObjects.Add(new Class2());
```

Like this? Because when I build a one-to-many relationship the collection seems to be instantiated automatically. Is that different to many-to-many relationships? Or is there an error or misbehaviour in my application when the collection *OtherObjects* is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do that.  Alternaltively,  you could instantiate the collection in your constructor.

Side note: I need to instantiate my collections when I have one-to-many.  I'm not sure why you don't need to.

Assuming the classes below.

```
public class Class1 {
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set;
  public Class2 OtherObject {get; set;}
}

public class Class2 {
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set;
  public List<Class1> OtherObjects {get; set;}
}
```

You can do this

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1();
class1.OtherObject = new Class2();
```

However, if you do the assignment the other way, you must instantiate your collection.

```
Class2 class2 = new Class2();
class2.OtherObjects = new List<Class1>(); //required
class2.OtherObjects.Add(new Class1());
```

Comment: I either don't know. But it worked... I'll keep an eye on that behaviour. Nevertheless, thanks for the info!